# When it is a good time for asking a raise after acquisition?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, communication, salary, raise

I used to work for a small software consulting company (less than 5 people) as a software developer. Recently we were informed we're being sold to a larger consulting company (almost 80 people) and our offices closed down because the new company is 100% remote. My boss invited us to breakfast before work one day and told us the news.

I was about to get a big raise for my second year being there but the old company was sold right around that time so I didn't get a raise. I was already getting underpaid. 9:1 is my billing rate to salary ratio and I work a lot more with this new company.

When is a good time to ask for a raise? It has been 3 months that my company was bought. My billable hours are 60 to 100 hours a month on average.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When is a good time to ask for a raise?

Now is always a good time.

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you for answering my question. I appreciate your time. It has been only 3 months since I have been working for them. It would be still professional to ask for a raise now, right?

Comment: Yes, a little bit more than two years. I get my raise once a year. I got one last year and last month was the time to get another raise but I didn't get it.

Comment: I'd say that asking now would be fine, since you were due. Just because you are now working for the new company doesn't mean you didn't provide the value to the company they purchased, and it doesn't mitigate the year of experience you gained prior to your intended raise-date.